OpenSSL 3.0 php distint values
I have a old project, with php 7.4 (OpenSSL 1.1.1k) and CentOS 8. Now in another machine have a php 7.4 (OpenSSL 3.0) and CentOS 9
I have a problem in the next function
default method = OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1

centos 8 openssl_verify($data, $signature, $pubKey) return 1

centos 9 openssl_verify($data, $signature, $pubKey) return -1
(error:03000098:digital envelope routines::invalid digest)
(error:02000068:rsa routines::bad signature)

What is the problem? I checked the same variables, but return distinct value. I activate the legacy mode in OpenSSL and it did not work, what else can I do to correct this problem?
[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
legacy = legacy_sect

[default_sect]
activate = 1

[legacy_sect]
activate = 1

